# Gibt es Regeln für die Pluralbildung von Phantasiewörtern?

Tags: grammatical-number

Hin und wieder begegnen uns reine Phantasiebegriffe oder Abwandlungen von existieren Wörtern, die mit einer Bedeutung belegt werden, etwa im literarischen Kontext. Wird der Plural benötigt, behilft man sich meistens mit einem angehängten 's', bei Wörtern, die auf 'e' enden, mit einem 'n', oder, wenn die Endung an ein bekanntes Wort erinnert, mit einer entsprechenden Ableitung (bei zusammengesetzten sinnfreien Wörtern wie 'Pferdeschachtel' wird der Plural natürlich vom zweiten Wort bestimmt - von denen ist hier nicht die Rede).

Beispiele: Dollenquille - Dollenquillen, Branst - Bransts.

Wie aber sieht es z. B. bei 'Simulacron' aus, lt. Wikipedia abgeleitet vom lateinischen 'Simulacrum' ('Trugbild')? "*Darf*" man einen Plural "*erfinden*", oder gibt es Regeln? Was spricht für 'Simulacrons', was für 'Simulacra' (intuitiv aus dem Lateinischen abgeleitet)?

Comment: Ich finde ja es müßte "Bränste" heißen. :-)

Comment: @starblue: Ein sehr schöner Kommentar, der die Frage um ein wunderbares Beispiel erweitert (im Ernst)! :-D

Comment: Ein Dollenquille, zwei Dollenquiller? Und Simulacron -> Simulacri?

Comment: @takrl Der *-i*-Plural ist mir nur für aus dem Lateinischen stammende Wörter geläufig, die mit *-us* oder *-um* enden. Simulacron gehört da ja nicht dazu.

Comment: Simulacronica ist correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es kommt auch darauf an, ob das Phantasiewort ein Eigenname ist oder nicht. Eigennamen sind im Deutschen nicht immer einfach zu pluralisieren, weil ein Eigenname ja gerade ein ganz bestimmtes Objekt, und nicht mehrere, bezeichnet. Die Sache wird weiter kompliziert, wenn ein Eigen- oder Markenname sich [zu einem Gattungsnamen entwickelt](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gattungsname#Schutz_f.C3.BCr_Produktnamen_.28Generalisierter_Markenname.29).

Edit:

Nomina haben drei Unterklassen:

[Eigennamen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenname), [Gattungsnamen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gattungsname), und [Stoffnamen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoffname). Stoffnamen können gar nicht direkt pluralisiert werden, Eigennamen hächstens unter Schmerzen (oder wenn sie sich, siehe oben, zum Gattungsnamen entwickeln).

Phantasie-Gattungsnamen kann der Erfinder erstmal so pluralisieren, wie der Erfinder es will, es ist ja schließlich ein Phantasiewort. Damit es "gut" klingt, orientiert man sich am besten am eigenen Sprachgefühl, und, sofern zutreffend, an den Plural-Regeln der Sprache, aus der das Phantasiewort abgeleitet wurde.

Comment: Informativ, dafür das "Accepted", mit Dank auch an bernd_k.

Answer (score 2):

Die Frage bedeutet doch praktisch, ob das Sprachgefühl einer größeren Gruppe von Sprechern die gleiche Pluralform wählt. Das passiert bei den meisten doch auf Grund des Sprachgefühls ohne formale Anwendung irgendwelcher Regeln.

Für mich ist 'Simulacrons' die naheliegende Form.

Comment: +1, tatsächlich ist es sogar so, dass Gruppen gleicher Sprache in der Mehrzahl automatisch dieselbe ("richtige") Form wählen. Regeln hin oder her, die hat man sich ja auch nicht komplett aus den Fingern gesaugt.